# Always update widget flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want a widget or something where my int automatically updates with my realtime database. Does anyone knows how i can do this. The code that i want to update the whole time is:

```
userid = _userId.replaceAll('#', "").replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "");
      DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("credits");
      final snapshot = await ref.child('$userid').get();
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        moneyd = snapshot.value.toString();
        print(snapshot.value);
      } else {
        print('No data available.');
      }
      print('hello $moneyd');
      if (int.tryParse(moneyd) != null) {
        money = int.tryParse(moneyd) ?? 0;
      } else {
        print('Invalid value for moneyd: $moneyd');
      }
```

The money value is now hard coded: money = 10; but i want it to be int money = int.parse(monyd);. I want this because, the string is 10 everytime that i restart the app but i want it to be the last saved string in firebase.

String moneyd = '';

Answer (score 0):

In this case, he will need to use a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html). FirebaseDatabase lets you [listen for events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_value_events):

```
StreamBuilder<Event>(
          stream: ref.child('credits')child('$userid').onValue,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              // Get a list of messages from snapshot data
              List<dynamic> data = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;

              moneyd = snapshot.value.toString();
              print(snapshot.value);
              // Return a ListView widget to display messages
              return Text(moneyd);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            } else {
              return Text('Loading...');
            }
          },
        ),
```

Comment: `databaseRef.child('credits')child('$userid').onValue` should be assigned to a variable in eg. initState and the variable used as the stream: property, otherwise it gets newly constructed everytime the build method runs and that can be expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the responds but i havn't defined databaseRef before, so what do i need to define it now?  How can i define value, the value is defined by defining snapshot and that now not defined.

Comment: That is just ref, I updated my answer

Comment: Event has to be DatabaseEvent btw :)

Comment: Do you also now where i need to define value or snapshot?